# WSO2 MessageBroker:Throwing javax.naming.NoInitialContextException error when act as publisher

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I have to access WSO2 Topic to publish data from my end. So i create a client but i am getting following exception when running

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at client.Class1.setTopic(Class1.java:53)
at client.Class1.main(Class1.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
... 5 more
```

My publisher code is .

```
    public static  void setTopic(String args) {
        //topic name
        String topicName = "Org_Hierarchy";

        //propertice object
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        //topic connection object
        TopicConnection topicConnection = null;

        //put connection factory in propertice 
        properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial",
                "org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory");

        //connection string
        String connectionString = "amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='some IP goes here'";



       //put connection string on propertice 
       properties.put("connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory", connectionString);

        try {
            // initialize the required connection factories
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);

            //get topic connection factory 
            TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory =
                    (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("topic");

            //get a connection from factory        
            topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();

            //create session from factory
            TopicSession topicSession =
                    topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            // create or use the topic
            Topic topic = topicSession.createTopic(topicName);
            TopicPublisher topicPublisher = topicSession.createPublisher(topic);
            TextMessage textMessage =
                    topicSession.createTextMessage(args);

            // publish the message
            topicPublisher.publish(textMessage);
            topicPublisher.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

What would be the issue for this scenario. I have only add javax.jms.jar file as external jars. Do i have to add WSO2 specific jars?

Comment: Looks as though you might not have the client jars in the class path. You can find the client jars inside of <MB_HOME>/client-lib

Comment: Hi @RaviU . is it required to have MB client jars in my java program? isnt it enough that i have jms only?

Comment: NVM  got it to working . yeah the issue was i did not had the required libraries :)